# Gridsearch in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I am searching over parameters in pipeline using `GridSearchCV` in Scikit.
I made my code work, but if I want to add `class_weights`, I am hitting a wall.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

RFC = RandomForestClassifier()
PCA = PCA()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('PCA', PCA), ('RFC', RFC)])

param_dict = {'RFC__n_estimators': [100,150],
              'RFC__class_weights': [{0:1,1:2},{0:1,1:4}],
              'PCA__n_components': [60,80]}

from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV             
estimator = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_dict, scoring='roc_auc')
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What is the proper way how to add this parameter to GridSearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple - You've got the wrong [parameter name](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html):

> **class_weight** : dict, list of dicts, “balanced”, “balanced_subsample” or None, optional

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thank you. I most likely delete the question, it does not deserve the megabites for store it.